# Searching in strings with special character using regular expressions

Tags: regex, apache-flex

I'm using regular expression to search word in a string, for example

```
var patrn:RegExp = new RegExp("\\bit's\\b");
var str:String = "Heres my problem in it and it's so help me guys.";
trace(patrn.exec(str)); //result is null
```

My problem is I can't search the data in a string which has special character like `('/,/.)`. What regular expression string is capable solving my problem?

Comment: the given example seems okay - can you post some more example that doesn't work as you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with regular expressions I always use http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ .